# Scala Docs in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scaladoc

How do I access Scala docs in IntelliJ? The other answers in SO are for earlier versions. I added the scala doc jar file, but still I am unable to link scala docs with IntelliJ.[image]

I do get the Quick Documentation as shown:
[image]

But I want the complete doc as [here](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4/?_ga=1.127400077.1418839130.1482121597#akka.actor.Actor)

Also, clicking on the Actor hyperlink shows me this code, but not the API doc. There are the download and Attach sources link and I dont understand what they are.
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What do you mean by "link scala docs"? You can get documentation for a symbol (class, method) **by pressing <kbd>Ctrl-Q</kbd>** (or menu View > Quick Documentation). This seems to work at least with sbt based projects, even if in Project Structure > Project Settings > Libraries > SBT: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.12.1:jar there is only classes and sources, and no explicit pointer to javadocs (I guess IntelliJ might extract them directly from the sources).

[image]

Also, are you using the latest version of IntelliIJ and the Scala plugin? For me, if I create a global Scala SDK (which you don't actually need when you use sbt build projects), IntelliJ by default does *not* have javadocs checked, but sources, and again I think it will extract the documentation from the sources. This is how it looks here with IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.1 and Scala plugin 2016.3.5:

[image]

Comment: @user567 looks like you are missing the sources for Akka. Is using an sbt project an option? That makes everything much easier, as IntelliJ will take care of downloading the library sources. Otherwise, check in Project Structure > Project Settings > Libraries > Akka that you have added Akka sources.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that my Akka sources are missing. Where can I get the Akka source docs as a jar file? I could not find it in the Akka website.

Comment: For example here: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22com.typesafe.akka%22%20a%3A%22akka-actor_2.11%22

Answer (score 0):

I added this:

[image: Scala Global Libraries] to make it work. From the +, choose Scala SDK, select the version that matches your project and then add it to the module of your choice.